# What phrases describe collisions with coefficients of restitution less than zero or greater than one?

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision, terminology

The [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) describes the elasticity of a collision:

- 1 = perfectly elastic, kinetic energy is conserved
- 0 = perfectly inelastic, the objects move at the same speed post impact

However, COR values > 1 and < 0 are also physically meaningful:

- COR > 1, a collision where the impact adds energy (e.g. an explosion)
- COR < 0, a partial collision where the objects partially pass through each other. Say, like this:

[image: apple and bullet]

Are there colloquial terms that characterize these types of collisions? Perhaps explosion does work well enough for the first case, but I can't think of anything that adequately describes the apple case.

(If inelastic is defined as COR != 1 it's probably broad enough but likely not very illuminating in practice.)

Comment: Maybe, reactions? Elastic, inelastic, endothermic, exothermic reactions?

Comment: ""# COR > 1, a collision where the impact adds energy (e.g. an explosion)
"" An impact adds energy? Where does he get that energy from?

Comment: @Georg well perhaps it's not very precise to say the impact is adding energy; rather, the impact is the catalyst for another form of energy to be released that then influences the post-impact mechanics. For example, if that apple was really a lump of high explosive, and if the act of getting hit with a bullet was enough to detonate it, then the detonation would convert previously stored chemical energy into kinetic energy, which would likely accelerate the post-collision particles/bodies and thus cause the observed COR to exceed 1.

Comment: Ahh, I see, this sounds better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For COR < 0 you can say *perforating* collision (or *piercing* or even *crossing*).

For COR > 1 one could use *exergonic* collision, but maybe that causes more confusion. This is taken from chemistry where there are [exergonic reactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergonic).

My two cents.